# Encode a Date and a four digit number into a string with max 8 characters

Tags: encoding

I have a datetime and a four digit number and I need to encode this into a 8 character case insensitive ASCII string.

The four digit number is not actually an arbitrary number, but there are only a certain numbers (about 20 or so) of the form (2513, 2595, 2579, ...).

My current approach is to use Base36 encoding. Further, I have a dictionary for the four digit numbers that maps like this:

```
2513 -> '00'
2595 -> '01'
...
```

The first two characters of the resulting string are used for this. The remaining six characters are used for encoding a unix timestamp with seconds stripped (I only need seconds resolution) in Base36.

So, (2513, 07.01.2015) maps to '000E3HEU'.

My question is, if anyone can think of an even more compact encoding?

Comment: Typo? `a unix timestamp with seconds stripped (I only need seconds resolution)`

Comment: What I mean is int(<unix timestamp>/60)